# Encode Array to UTF-8 and get values to an input text

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, arrays

I have a little problem, base on few examples I have manages to get data from one file into another file using Ajax, using echo in my query, but now I'd like to use the json_ecode(); but for some reason is not working I hope someone can explain what am I doing wrong and hopefully provide an example.

So here is what I got:

File: query.php

```
// include your config file or not.. depends on how you do it, I like to always have a config file to connect to a DB or anything else...    
if(isset($_GET['valrq'])) {
// Clean the request
// transform the value to an int // maybe to much cleaning....
// Do the SQL Query
// if Value exist in DB
// Get values in array
// lets make it clean array, because we don't want all of the columns in the db just a few
   $arr = array (
        'location' => $locationdb,
        'city' => $citydb,
        'state' => $statedb,
);
$result['keys'] = array_map("utf8_encode", $arr);
// lets "print" the array
echo json_encode($result);

} else {
  $err='Zip Code is not valid';
 }
```

And that will output an array as follow:

> {"keys":{"location":"Sn. Barnabas","city":"Oxon hill","state":"MD"}}

of curse the url something like this: .com/query.php?valrq=20745

where 20745 is a zip code I guess you already know where this is going...

Until this point everything is working "fine"

now here is where I have my first help request..

The DB that I have is a dump that a fund it contain zip codes cities and states, but some of the values are with accented letters something like [ ó, é, í, ñ, Ñ...] some other looks like a Russian characters... so at first I thought well I can change one by one to an ASCII code, but.. there are more than 60K records so no can do, then for that particular column I change it from utf8_general_ci    to utf8_unicode_ci but that only made it worst ... why? ...

If my values from the DB are á which is á then there is not problem everything will be fine, but the actual value is a raw symbol o accented letter as á or æ ... and now it display something like

> {"keys":{"location":"Sn. B**\u00c1l**rnabas","city":"Oxon hill","state":"MD"}}

so how can I get the actual symbol or accented letter as I have it in my SQL...?

and now my second problem... based on what I have if I don't use the json_encode or print_r or any array and instead of an array I display the info using and echo such as echo $citydb; echo $statedb; ... and so on then I get something like

> Sn. BarnabasOxon hillMD

which can be fix with br's echo $val.br; and in return I get

```
Sn. Barnabas
Oxon hill
MD
```

any way, the weird part is that by using this method I do get the symbols and accented letters no problem...

So my html and "ajax" is as follow:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test Ajax Fetch SQL Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode">
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city">
    <input type="text" name="state" id="state">
</form> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#zipcode').keyup(function () {
    var zp = $(this);
    if (zp.val().length == 5) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'query.php',
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            data: "valrq=" + zp.val(),
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.status) {
                    $('#city').val(data.keys.city);
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

With that code I got nothing... but if I change the json_encode to just echo, then I do get the info right where I need it...

all I have to do is replace this line

```
if(data.status) {
$('#city').val(data.keys.city);
}
```

for

```
$('#city').val(data);
```

just that, I get the data in to my input field problem is that not just any data but the whole thing

so as you can see I have two problems...
1.- the character set in the DB, if the character has í or â or any of those the array return a null in the value...
2.- once I have the array I need the values so I can put those values in my input boxes.

I even tried the SET CHARACTER SET utf8 but it didn't do a thing...

Thank you for taking the time...

---

Edit - Add info.
For the encode Part UTF-8

```
Table 1
col 1 | col 2 | col 3
ó     | &oacute | o

echo $col1;
return ó
echo json_encode($col1);
return \90si\ (more or less) ...
```

anyway, the encode part is not longer needed, the reason is, that when I use Json_encode(); I get symbols and hex's not the actual data stored in the DB so, instead I'm using print_r() this way I don't have to worry about encoding to utf-8 or ISO... 
So my previews array was like this:

> {"keys":{"location":"Sn. Barnabas","city":"Oxon hill","state":"MD"}}

and now is like this:

```
Array
(
    [location] => Sn. Barnabas
    [city] => Oxon Hill
    [state] => MD
)
```

that array is in "query.php"
now what I want to achieve is to get the those values and use them as values for input boxes which they are in form.php the html still the same as the above with a minor change on the ajax...

```
$('#zipcode').keyup(function () {
    var zp = j(this);
    if (zp.val().length == 5) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'query.php',
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            data: "valrq" + zp.val(),
            success: function (data) {

         $('#city').val(data);

            }
        })
    }
});
```

what I get with that is the whole thing, what I mean is whatever returns from query.php is my "data" ... what I need is to get the actual values for each key

```
> $('#location').val(data.location);
> $('#state').val(data.state);
> $('#city').val(data.city);
```

but is not working...

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you are asking, give a concrete example for 1 problematic row: what is stored in the DB, what does echo return, what does json_encode return? also show what `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%' ` returns

Comment: Hello @Dr.Molle I just added some code at the end, I hope that is more simple, I also change the output for my array, before i was using json_encode, and now just print_r() ... thank you.

Comment: I don't see any problem here, `"Sn. B\u00c1lrnabas"` is a valid JSON encoding for `"Sn. BÁlrnabas"`. When you read this value in JavaScript the engine automatically transforms escape sequences into characters, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/DRm99/

Comment: \90si\ ...that's really what json_encode  returns?

Comment: I see, I was so worry about the whole utf-8 and ISO and utf8_encode ... that I was going directly to .com/query.php?valrq=222 and I was getting that \u00c1l which for the result was wrong, the problem is that I never got the values in the actual html file... any way, I don't wactyally need that any more, what I need is to get thoes values... and yes @Dr.Molle json_encode() return that \u00c1l ... as I had it $return['keys'] = $array_map('utf8_encode', $arr); but not longer now I need to know how to get those values... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. Just use `json_encode()` normally. Sequences such as `\u00c1` are correct and to be expected. The JavaScript engine transforms them into corresponding characters automatically.

```
// value returned by AJAX request
var data = {"keys":{"city":"test \u00f3 \u00e9 \u00ed \u00f1"}};

$('#city').val(data.keys.city);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/zpjD6/ for the output.

And don't forget to tell jQuery that you expect JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    dataType: 'json',
    ...
});
```

Comment: What you are telling me, is that.. I was running around looking for an orange when the orange was on my hand and the only thing I needed was a knife (**dataType: 'json',**) to cut it... burn! ... lol omg, I encoded the SQL query, I encoded the array, i print it, i json and encoded and after a few hrs the only thing I needed was to tell jQuery what type of data i was expecting [DATATYPE!!!!] Thank you... now is working!